# How to run sbt assembly command with a custom file path defined?

Tags: java, linux, scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am working on a code generator program which is written in java. I have no problem on generating the scala project structure. However I could not run the sbt assembly command due to I am not in the directory. At my java program I could not use cd function to get to the directory. Is there any way to run sbt assembly by specifying the destination of my project folder?